# Which Material Design Component for Chat messages

Tags: angular, material-design, chat, angular-material

Which components should I use for a chat message list? On http://material.io I can't find any examples.

[Example](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/04/a2/25/04a225746f15436e5ec6f3c3112a27d3--mobile-app-material-design.jpg): The right version is the commonly used style for apps like Hangouts and other messengers. More rounded versions like the left versions are starting to pop up like with Google Allo or Android Messengers.

In the lists section there is a list shown like the list of contacts I wrote to. But those don't show history with one contact. I search for a solution for Angular-Material but am interested in general on the design principles behind the message list which do have an arrow pointing to the avatar.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by "chat message list"?

Comment: You should probably use a list view.